# Display text window over top of list view

Tags: android

I have a list view with 10 or so items. Each has a corresponding text file. I can right now determine when and which element is pressed. My issue is being able to display the text file overtop of the list view. I tried putting in a Text view and making it visable when pressed but it crashes the app. How can I on press of a list view element have a pop up text view open without starting a new intent.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dialog with a `TextView`!

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Good luck!